Creating new Transaction for Spring Batch Writer while handling Error Listener
I have a spring batch job where the Writer gets a list of items. I am using chunk oriented processing. My spring batch chunk size is 100. I have enabled fault tolerant for the step. Since the writer gets a list of items where for each item am doing a Kafka send and a db write, if say 70th item fails, Spring Batch will end up reprocessing all the items of the chunk in individual transaction including reprocessing of earlier 69 ones. Now, i do not want these 69 to get reprocessed. Also, i do not want to create individual transactions to write each item. I was thinking of adding a try catch and handling the failure ones myself. Can I atleast use the error listener to propagate in case of any errors? Are there any better recommendations?
